# Invalid object name

Tags: java, sql-server

When doing...

```
select * from students
```

I get a "Invalid object name" error.  Basically, I think I can see the problem in that the tables are prefixed with an object name rather than just dbo, lets call the schema "test".

So this means....

```
select * from test.students
```

The problem I have is that I can't change the SQL code (it's in release, long story) or change the tables.  My question is, is there anything I can change in SQL server that will allow me to connect say with a specific SQL server user so I can still run my queries as...

```
select * from students
```

Omitting the object name, but still have the object name against the table?  I can add another SQL user or something like that no problem.

I'm using Java over the jdbc protocol, so my connection string is something like jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:port;databaseName=db;user=myuser;password=mypassword

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a default schema option, which doesn't exist for a given connection.  That is to say that you can't say something like "until I say otherwise, unqualified tables are in the test schema".  You can, however, set a default schema for a user.  For your example, you'd do

```
alter user [myuser] with default_schema = [test]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the connection string and set your default catalog to your "test" database

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial
Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;"
providerName="SqlDataClient"/>
```

Comment: Ah, I'm connecting via JDBC, I'm not sure if this still exists this way, I'll add it to my post

Comment: Initial Catalog in SQL Server means "what database is the default for this connection".